# Hibernate mapping: using same object multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javafx

I have a small problem regarding hibernate mappings:

What I need is the following :

I have Class `Car`, and class `Worker`.

I have mapped them as `@ManyToOne`. Where `@ManyToOne` is on car side:

//this is my field in car class i use javafx properties

```
private ObjectProperty<Monter> monter= new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

 @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")
public Worker getWorker() {
    return worker.get();
}
```

and in the worker side is following

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy ="worker",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Car> getCar() {
    return car;
}
```

And this works, I have no issues, however, I need to have 3 fields for worker, `workerIn`, `workerOut`,`workerMain`.

So how can I make more fields in my Car class, so I can store my workers in them, since when i try to create new `ObjectProperty<Worker>` i get error from hibernate that it cannot find out field type.

So, i am not sure, am i using the wrong mapping ? should i be using manyToMany,
or should i annotate every single field i create in Car class?

Basicly user would be prompted to choose, workerIn, workerOut,workerMain, from list of workers, and i could not achive this, and creating 3 lists for this would be insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a join table as this looks like a many to many mapping scenario.

So the table would have columns (watch out for the worker_type discriminator):

```
worker_id
car_id
worker_type
```

In the Car class you would have:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
      name="car_worker",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "worker_type = 1")
private Set<Worker> workerIn;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
      name="car_worker",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "worker_type = 2")
private Set<Worker> workerOut;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
      name="car_worker",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "worker_type = 3")
private Set<Worker> workerMain;
```

The Worker class would have:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
      name="car_worker",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="WORKER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
private Set<Car> cars;
```

Comment: I am affraid i dont understand this completly, how would i set now my workers:
i have now a gui, where i want to create my new Car, and i want to assign a worker, for one role, or maybe one worker for two roles. but now my car.setMainWorker() or any other, is accepting Set<Worker> and not the worker it self, i cant manage to solve this.

Comment: You have to add them to a particular Set Raphael (and the to the cars Set on the Worker itself). The type of worker is defined in the jointable.worker_type (i assumed an interger but this can be other type)

Comment: Thank you, i managed to make this work properly, thank you very much.